# Did we really discover antimatter on planet Earth?

Tags: antimatter

Scientists say that they discovered the positron, how is this possible, and when the positron reaches the atmosphere, it will annihilate because of its encounter with ordinary matter.  How can antimatter survive and reach Earth safely?

Comment: their lifetime is short until they indeed annihilate 1 equivalent of antimatter annihilates with 1 equivalent of matter, so maybe (I'm no expert and a noob in this area) one requires equivalent antimass to annihilate some mass and vise versa, so no problem in creating antimatters in huge particle colliders if it indeed annihilates up within a couple of microseconds!

Comment: @prikarsartam In general a positrons lifetime is not short at all, since it does not decay by itself. It does annihilate with an electron, but both particles are stable.

Comment: Here is the experimental discovery https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron#Experimental_clues_and_discovery

Answer (score 1):

Only a small fraction of the so-called cosmic rays, which are actually high energy particles from different astrophysical sources that reach the Earth are antimatter, and you are right: If they are antimatter, they annihilate as soon as they hit some corresponding matter particle (for example when a positron hits an electron) in the atmosphere. Nevertheless, I think it is not impossible for them to reach the ground before they annihilate. *But*, way more importantly, they can also be produced as a product of a collision of some other high energetic cosmic particle, which is not necessarily antimatter itself, here on Earth. Most of these 'cosmic rays' are high energy protons. The positron is then a secondary particle of a cascade of particle interactions originating from such a collision of matter from Earth with a 'cosmic ray'. Looking at the traces of particles in cloud chambers and how they bend in magnetic fields lead to the discovery of the positron. Look [here](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.43.491) for one of the original papers.

Maybe you are not aware of that, but positrons are also produced on Earth, without the help of cosmic rays, and not only in particle accelerators, but for example also in your own body, in [radioactive $\beta^+$ decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay) (look that up on Wikipedia to understand, how positrons can arise from 'ordinary matter'), for example by the decay of Potassium.